# Is mining with my computer worth it?

Tags: bitcoind

I have a computer with a Phenom II X6 1090T 3.2 GHz, and a GT430 gfx card. Obviously I know I won't be able to mine lots of bitcoins, but I want to start getting some money for a car and such. Is the only solution to mining by getting a ASIC Machine, or people on other forums run a pool using a huge botnet.

If you guys can give me any tips to start, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So according to this wiki[1] your GT430 can run at 20 MHash/s. And if you plug 20 MHash/s into the mining calculator[2] you're looking at around $0.08 a day in revenue. Your daily power consumption will be larger than that.

Or to think of that another way, the current rates mean $0.41 USD/24h@100MHash/s, and you're one-fifth of that.

8 cents per day. That's a long way to save for a car.

[1] https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison
[2] http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/